# Manually Sorting Sub-Group of Users?

Tags: users, sorting

I just built a membership site and created a Member Directory template which includes all users and then a Board Members Directory template which only lists users who have a "Board Member Title" custom user field filled out in their user profile.

I sort the Member Directory page by last name, but my client would like to be able to **manually** sort the board members on the Board Members Directory page.

In trying to keep things DRY, I like that in order to turn somebody into a board member, as an admin, I simply add content to the Board Member Title field and I'm done.

Originally I was thinking of something like the old Low Reeorder used to be for EE, but haven't come across anything like that for Craft yet.

Hoping there's an elegant solution I'm just not thinking of. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By manual sort, do you mean the ability to drag/drop rearrange?

Comment: Exactly or really any way to manually specify the order of just the board members that won't blow up if I need to reorder them ever. I thought about a custom "order" integer field but that would suck if I need to reorder ever.

Comment: The users solution I noted in Slack not work?

Comment: I can make that work, but it's not very intuitive and causes an extra, outside step anytime you add a board member. Plus, I wasn't a fan of how the users field lists the selected users horizontally and not vertically so it's hard to see the true top to bottom order. Again, it will probably be what I use if I can't find something more elegant.

Comment: I think you'll need an extra step whatever solution you choose. But yeah, relationship/user fields ui in Craft is a bit of a sore point for us too. Wish it were like old P&T Playa.

Comment: Any creative solutions Brad or is my only option to create a global with a Users field and rig something up that way?